# SUMIFS across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

So I'm working on a workbook right now that is across 3 sheets, 'Data', 'RAW', 'Lookup'. On the Data tab it looks like, Sheet 1

```
A              B          C        D          E
Segment     Ranking    Amount    Revenue   Spend
Carbon         15         2       5000      550
Oxygen         30         3       6895      450
Minerals       45         1       4400      350
```

The Code I use for each column are as follows (Some of the Columns are named columns)

```
B =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OK",$A2))),SUMIFS(RAW!B:B,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*"),SUMIFS(RAW!B:B,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*",Output,"<>*OK*"))

C =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OK",$A2))),SUMIFS(RAW!C:C,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*"),SUMIFS(RAW!C:C,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*",SegmentName,"<>*OK*"))

D =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OK",$A2))),SUMIFS(RAW!D:D,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*"),SUMIFS(RAW!D:D,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*",Output,"<>""OK"))

E =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OK",$A2))),SUMIFS(Spend,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*"),SUMIFS(Spend,Output,"*"&INDEX(SegmentID,MATCH($A2,SegmentName,0))&"*",Output,"<>*OK*"))
```

The RAW Sheet looks like (Sheet 2)

```
A                          B           C        D          E
Output                  Ranking     Amount   Revenue     Spend 
Random_1234_Random         15          2       5000       550
Random_5678_Random         30          3       6895       450
Random_9102_Random         45          1       4400       350
Random_555_Random          60          4       4000       300
```

The Lookup Sheet Looks like (Sheet 3)

```
A               B
Segment        ID
Carbon         1234
Oxygen         5678
Minerals       9102
Carbon         555
```

The problem that I have right now is, it will only grab the first Carbon with ID 1234, and not grab the second Carbon with ID 555 at all resulting in:

```
A                  B         C         D         E
Segment         Ranking   Amount    Revenue    Spend
Carbon             15       2        5000       550
```

The end result that I would like is for it to grab ALL Carbon with any ID and add all of them together as below into a single line. (RAW sheet, Random_1234_Random + Random_555_Random)

```
A              B        C         D          E
Segment    Ranking    Amount    Revenue    Spend
Carbon         75       6        9000       850
```

Any help would be great and if I need to provide more detail please let me know!

Thank you in advance,
Maykid

Comment: I know you tried to explain really thoroughly, but please try to be more specific about where your problem is. It's kind of confusing when you jump between the sheets in your explanation

Comment: And be consistent in what you show. Where did the carbon ranking of 75 come from? It was 15. The expected output should have a logical link to the input. Is it part of another row you added to the data sheet?

Comment: The problem that I have is, if I add another Carbon the formula now will only pick up the Carbon with ID 1234, and not the Carbon with ID 555. I want to have it so it picks up both Carbons and add each column together. What I mean by this is, on the RAW sheet, there is Random_1234_Random & Random_555_Random both of these are Carbon. I want to be able to have the formula add both of these together as one Carbon, so 60+15, 2+4, 5000+4000, 550+300 hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Does your **Output** *always* have an underscore before and after the ID number?

Comment: @TotsieMae Yes, the **Output** Always has an underscore before and after. But that is not the only underscore in the lines that I pull from, up above is just an example of the pull.

Comment: For your defined names, can you please tell us what data they are associated with? For example, is **Output** located on `RAW!A2:A5`?

Comment: @TotsieMae Definitely, so **Output** is `RAW!A:A` **Spend** is `RAW!E:E` **SegmentID** is `Lookup!B:B` **SegmentName** is `Lookup!A:A`